# SQL 'where statement' without joining

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

Is it possible to do a `WHERE` statement without joining it to other tables?
For example:

```
Table1(t1_id,name)

Table2(t2_id, fk_t1_id, something)

Table3(t3_id, fk_t2_id, blah)
```

I want to do this:

```
SELECT name, something 
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON t1_id = fk_t1_id 
WHERE blah = 'somestring'
```

or do I have to join table3 too, for the `WHERE` statement to work?

Comment: Without joining to table 3, the `WHERE` statement isn't going to have any effect on the output if you aren't having conditions from table 1 or 2 in the `WHERE` statement

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm new to SQL so it's just a comprehension question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to join table3.  There's no way for the query parser to know that you want something from that table or do a comparison unless you include the table in the query.

```
SELECT name, something
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.t1_id = t2.fk_t1_id
JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.t2_id = t3.fk_t2_id
WHERE t3.blah = 'somestring'
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example you need `Table3` in order to get to the `blah` column.  The other two tables do not know what `blah` is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to join Table3.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a substring in where condition

```
SELECT name, something 
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON t1_id = fk_t1_id 
WHERE blah IN (Select blah from table3)
```

Comment: I am not sure what db you are using but this works in MS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

A semi-join would work as opposed to an inner join on table3:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.something
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.t1_id = t2.fk_t1_id
WHERE t2.t2_id IN (SELECT fk_t2_id FROM table3 WHERE blah = 'something')
```